# How to discover whether Geo-tagging is enabled with Twitter / MGTwitterEngine?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, geotagging, mgtwitterengine

Using Matt Gemmell's MGTwitterEngine, how would I find out if the user (that i'm logged in as) has geo tagging enabled?
According to the Twitter API, there is a 'geo_enabled' boolean flag, but I can't work out how to interrogate it using MGTwitterEngine.
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Geotagging-API-Best-Practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do getUserInformationFor: on the current user and check if string for key "geo_enabled" is equal to string "true", as in 
`[[userInfo objectForKey:@"geo_enabled"] isEqualToString:@"true"];`

Comment: Not sure how to do this, I'm trying:
NSString *theName = [_engine username];
NSLog(@"Name %@", theName);
NSString *theInfo = [_engine getUserInformationFor:theName];
NSLog(@"Info %@", theInfo);

.. but theInfo just returns a random string, like A2B6D0D5-A579-4122-831A-B3355242B684.

Comment: You will need to implement userInfoReceived:forRequest: in your engine delegate. Once the result for your getUserInformationFor: request is ready and parsed, the engine will call userInfoReceived:forRequest: with the first argument of NSArray of NSDictionary-ies with user info and NSString, containing the same ID as you get as getUserInformationFor's return value.